# Why does python memory allocation behave like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

Consider the following code which is used for finding all valid parentheses placements with n parentheses.

```
def paren(n):
    ans = []
    def helper(string, left, right,n,foo):
        if len(string)==2*n:
            ans.append(string)
        if left > 0:
            helper(string+'(', left-1,right,n)
        if right > left:
            helper(string+')', left,right-1,n)
    helper('',n,n,n)
```

If we add a list (that has no practical use in the function) we get

```
def paren(n):
    ans = []
    def helper(string, left, right,n,foo):
        print(hex(id(foo)), foo)
        if len(string)==2*n:
            ans.append(string)
        if left > 0:
            helper(string+'(', left-1,right,n,[])
        if right > left:
            helper(string+')', left,right-1,n,[])
    helper('',n,n,n,[])
    
paren(2)

OUTPUT:

0x2e5e2446288 []
0x2e5e28e3508 []
0x2e5e28e3688 []
0x2e5e26036c8 []
0x2e5e27bafc8 []
0x2e5e28e3688 []
0x2e5e26036c8 []
0x2e5e27bafc8 []
```

Whereas if we explicitly pass foo each time then we get

```
def paren(n):
    ans = []
    def helper(string, left, right,n,foo):
        print(hex(id(foo)), foo)
        if len(string)==2*n:
            ans.append(string)
        if left > 0:
            helper(string+'(', left-1,right,n,foo)
        if right > left:
            helper(string+')', left,right-1,n,foo)
    helper('',n,n,n,[])
    
paren(2)

OUTPUT:

0x1c2cfec6288 []
0x1c2cfec6288 []
0x1c2cfec6288 []
0x1c2cfec6288 []
0x1c2cfec6288 []
0x1c2cfec6288 []
0x1c2cfec6288 []
0x1c2cfec6288 []
```

**In the first case we get a different object in memory, why is this compared to the second case when we don't I think it is to do with with the fact that we create a new list rather than passing the function argument?**

However when we add something to foo we get the same behaviour as with the first case:

```
def paren(n):
    ans = []
    def helper(string, left, right,n,foo):
        print(hex(id(foo)), foo)
        if len(string)==2*n:
            ans.append(string)
        if left > 0:
            helper(string+'(', left-1,right,n,foo+['bar'])
        if right > left:
            helper(string+')', left,right-1,n,foo+['bar'])
    helper('',n,n,n,[])
    
paren(2)

OUTPUT:

0x269572e6288 []
0x26959283548 ['bar']
0x26957363688 ['bar', 'bar']
0x2695925ae88 ['bar', 'bar', 'bar']
0x26957363408 ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']
0x2695925ae88 ['bar', 'bar']
0x26957363408 ['bar', 'bar', 'bar']
0x269592833c8 ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']
```

But strangely if we pass some int for foo, I will take 5 for demonstration we get:

```
def paren(n):
    ans = []
    def helper(string, left, right,n,foo):
        print(hex(id(foo)), foo)
        if len(string)==2*n:
            ans.append(string)
        if left > 0:
            helper(string+'(', left-1,right,n,5)
        if right > left:
            helper(string+')', left,right-1,n,5)
    helper('',n,n,n,5)
    
paren(2)

OUTPUT:

0x7ffef47293c0 5
0x7ffef47293c0 5
0x7ffef47293c0 5
0x7ffef47293c0 5
0x7ffef47293c0 5
0x7ffef47293c0 5
0x7ffef47293c0 5
0x7ffef47293c0 5
```

i.e. the same point in memory.

However if I replace the 5 in the above code with a larger int for instance 2550 I get the following:

```
0x2519f6d4790 2550
0x2519f9ec6f0 2550
0x2519f9ec6f0 2550
0x2519f9ec6f0 2550
0x2519f9ec6f0 2550
0x2519f9ec6f0 2550
0x2519f9ec6f0 2550
0x2519f9ec6f0 2550
```

**So initially it is stored at a different memory address but each subsequent call is at the same address. Why is this changing from the case foo=5 what is going on here?**

Also in examples where the memory address is changing between calls I do see the same memory addresses being used on more than one occasion for example:

```
...
0x2695925ae88 ['bar', 'bar', 'bar']
...
0x2695925ae88 ['bar', 'bar']
...
```

**Why is this the case? Is python using previously used memory addresses to store new variables once the old ones are no longer on the recursion call stack?**

My mind is really fuzzy on these behaviours so if anyone could help me out that would be great!

I have heard of things like pass by reference and pass by value, but I am not too sure what they mean and if it relates to this python example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First code: the call stack keeps a reference to each `foo`, so you have many lists in memory at once, each with a unique ID.

Second code: you pass the *same* list (that was initially empty) to each recursive call.

Third code: Cpython, as an implementation-specific optimization, caches small `int` constants for reuse

Fourth code Cpython does *not* cache large (i.e., greater than 256), so each occurrence of 2550 creates a new `int` object.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. One last point to ask though, you say that large values are not cached but if I declare two variables `x = 1, y = 1000` and print the memory addresses they have the same address all the time even though `y > 256` so it should have a different location right? Also if we take an address say `0x2519f6d4790` for example how many bits of information does this address hold?

Comment: Also for the last example with `2550` you say this is not cached but then why do each recursive call store 2550 at the same location (with the exception of the initial call)? Surely the value `2550` as it is not cached would be stored in a separate location for each instance on the call stack?

Comment: I believe that's a separate implementation-specific optimization. When the code for `helper` is generated, the literal 2550 is allocated once as a "local" constant, and every *call* to `helper` uses the same object.

Comment: In general, it is not worth worrying about whether a *literal* produces a new object or reuses an existing object. Your code should not be written to depend on one scenario or the other. Object identity should only be used to test if two *name*s refer to the same object or not, due to explicit assignment (and such use cases are relatively rare).

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain this behavior to you with a generic explanation.

Python differentiates between reference data types and primitive data types.
Reference data types save references in the memory to a stored value and not the value them self. On the other hand primitive (or value) data types save the value itself.

If you pass an array to a method it will create a new instance of this array every time. So doing `some_function([])` generates a new array and passes it to the function. This means calling `some_function([])` and then `some_function([])` again will create one array on each call. However, if you create an array like `foo = []` then foo will reference to the array and calling `some_function(foo)` and then `some_function(foo)` will execute `some_function` on this array.

This is not happening for values like float, int, boolean, but for values like objects and arrays.

Follow up research can be done by following keywords: reference data type, value data type, built in types.

I hope my answer was helpful in understanding the stated problem.